# How to handle multiple 'GET' endpoints in a Flask-Restplus response class

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

I'm just starting learning Flask and are trying to create a simple API dealing with a data processing backend (named ATExplorer).

I started by creating a 'backend' namespace, i.e. backendAPI:

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint, redirect, url_for
from flask_restplus import Resource, Api
from werkzeug.routing import Rule

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.SWAGGER_UI_DOC_EXPANSION = 'list'
blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__, url_prefix='/api')
api = Api(blueprint, version=0.1, title='AT Pipeline API', doc='/swagger/')
app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
backendAPI = api.namespace('backend', description='Manage ATExplorer backend API.')
```

I want two endpoints, *version*, returning the version of the backend, e.g. 0.1 and *status*, returning the status of the backend, e.g. 'stopped', or 'running'

I created a response class and routes like this:

```
@backendAPI.route('/version', methods=['GET'])
@backendAPI.route('/status',  methods=['GET'])

class Backend(Resource):

     def get(self):
        #How to differentiate between the ../backend/version call and a 
        # ../backend/status call here??
        #if call is for status:
        #     return {'status': 'running'}
        #elif call is for version
        #     return {'version': '0.1'}
```

Guess this is a question of design. What 'design' is preferable for this case?

---- EDIT -----
The above code can be rewritten, achieving a desired end (client) result by the following:

```
class Backend(Resource):
    def __init__(self, api=None, *args, **kwargs):
         #The 'actual' backend resource
         self.backend = atp.backend

@backend_api.route('/status',  methods=['GET'])
class Dummy(Backend):
     def get(self):
         return {'status':self.backend.getStatus()}

@backend_api.route('/version',  methods=['GET'])
class Dummy(Backend):
     def get(self):
         return {'status':self.backend.getVersion()}
```

It seem flask allow multiple classes with the same name, doing different things based on the 'route' decorator, i.e. the class name is **irrelevant**.

Is there a 'text-book' way to express the above logic?

Comment: I wouldn't use the same class name. It's much less readable and it appears as if the two classes are connected somehow (logic-wise).

Comment: Well, I'm concerned about a framework that allow such code to be written, and executed, in the first place.. sounds like the above is better expressed using something like an anonymous struct often used in C/C++. 
Would be useful to see a case where the class name actually matter.

Comment: I'm not a `flask-restplus` savvy but I'm pretty sure that the class name matters for readability, nothing more.

Comment: It also messes with the UI provided (i.e. when clicking on a route that holds the same classname, it scrolls to the first one )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's more of a `flask_restplus` question, because in Flask you usually use methods as routes.

Anyway, have you considered using two different classes for two different actions?

```py
@backendAPI.route('/version', methods=['GET'])
class Version(Resource):
    def get(self):
         return flask.jsonify({"version_number": "0.1"})

@backendAPI.route('/status', methods=['GET'])
class Status(Resource):
    def get(self):
         return flask.jsonify({"status": "running"})
```

Comment: Thanks @AdamGold, I ended up using your approach. 

Seem like a lot of overhead, unfortunately.